# SELECT query using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I don't know why the following query is not working:

```
SELECT whs_code, pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd, fresh_frozen_status, 
SUM(qty_cases_on_hand)-Qty, SUM(qty_weight_on_hand)-Wt, operation
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd,fresh_frozen_status,operation,SUM(qty_cases_on_hand) AS Qty, SUM(qty_weight_on_hand) AS Wt
            FROM tbl_inventory_activity_rpt1 
                WHERE operation ='RU'
                GROUP BY whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd,fresh_frozen_status,operation 
    ) 
    WHERE operation='SU'
    GROUP BY whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd,fresh_frozen_status,operation`
```

The error is :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

To make it simple to understand what i am trying to do here, please see the example 
I need data as result of

```
(SELECT x FROM tbl_table Where column y='SU')-(SELECT x FROM tbl_table Where column y='RU')
```

Comment: What does "not working" means here?, does it throws an error?, wrong results?, what?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Please remove the "" and the & _. Also line break and indent your query so one can read it properly.

Comment: You dont have columns qty_cases_on_hand,qty_weight_on_hand anymore in your inner query..

Comment: Also how can you retrieve operation='SU' if your inner query has already a filter on 'RU' ?

Comment: That's what i am concerned i am trying to get the data as a result of 'SU'-RU'

Comment: You need to be more clear with the question.. This query is not correct way to solve your problem....

Comment: Okay.. now you posted the right ques... You would like to do SU-RU only for those common values?

Comment: Yah sum(qty_cases_on_hand) with operation 'SU' - sum(qty_cases_on_hand) with operation 'RU'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT ru.whs_code,
           ru.pdt_code,
           ru.case_dt_yyyymmdd,
           ru.fresh_frozen_status,
           ru.operation,
           ru.Qty - su.Qty AS Qty_Diff,
           ru.Wt - su.Wt AS Wt_Diff
      FROM    
    (
        SELECT whs_code,
               pdt_code,
               case_dt_yyyymmdd,
               fresh_frozen_status,
               operation,
               SUM(qty_cases_on_hand) AS Qty, 
               SUM(qty_weight_on_hand) AS Wt
          FROM tbl_inventory_activity_rpt1 
         WHERE operation ='RU'
       GROUP BY whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd,fresh_frozen_status,operation 
    ) ru,
    (
        SELECT whs_code,
               pdt_code,
               case_dt_yyyymmdd,
               fresh_frozen_status,
               operation,
               SUM(qty_cases_on_hand) AS Qty, 
               SUM(qty_weight_on_hand) AS Wt
          FROM tbl_inventory_activity_rpt1 
         WHERE operation ='SU'
       GROUP BY whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd,fresh_frozen_status,operation 
    ) su
WHERE ru.whs_code = su.whs_code
  AND ru.pdt_code = su.pdt_code
  AND ru.case_dt_yyyymmdd = su.case_dt_yyyymmdd
  AND ru.fresh_frozen_status = su.fresh_frozen_status
  AND ru.operation = su.operation;
```

Comment: That Works @Teja, What if i want all the rows which are 'SU' and not 'RU'

Comment: Change the alias from ru to su in your outer query.